# Standard Deviation of Bernoulli trials / Bernoulli process with different probabilities

Tags: standard-deviation, poisson-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-process, bernoulli-process

If 20 independent Bernoulli trials are carried out each with a different probability of success and therefore failure, what is the standard deviation of the result? How is this calculated?

Comment: what is the result?

Comment: Are the probabilities all known? If so, just use basic properties of variances. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties